# knockoutjs change view with bindig

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to show and hide selected views with knockout js api. My view models are like this.

```
var profileModel = {
    first: ko.observable("First name"),
    last: ko.observable("Last name"),
};

var settingsModel = {
    isActive: ko.observable(true)        
};

var notificationsModel = {
    emailAddress: ko.observable("sample@mail.net")  
};
```

And I have a shell `viewmodel` to manage sub **viewmodels**:

```
var shellModel = {
    sections: ["profile", "settings", "notifications"],
    selectedSection: ko.observable(),   
}
ko.applyBindings(shellModel);
```

My navigation view looks like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: sections">
   <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.selectedSection, text: $data"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks this link, the selected view should appear, and the others should not appear.

Profile view is like this.

```
<div data-bind="with: ???">
    <div id="profile">
        <input data-bind="value: first" />
        <input data-bind="value: last" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind:"click: ???">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: dynamic context switching is troublesome in current ko. You could wait for knockout component which is planned in knockout v3.2, or have a look at http://pagerjs.com/demo/

Answer (score 1):

create close function in every view model, on click of this it will show default or home view and hide the current view.

```
var profileModel = {
 first: ko.observable("Bob"),
 last: ko.observable("Smith"),
 closeit: function () {
    shellModel.selectedSection("default");
 }
};
```

close button binding:-

```
 <input type="button" data-bind="click: closeit" value="close" />
```

Then default view:-

```
<div data-bind="visible: selectedSection() === 'default'">
    <div id="default">
        <div>Home page</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AdY9V/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: sections">
   <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.sectionChangedClick, text: name"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="with: selectedSection">
    <div id="profile">
        <input data-bind="value: first" />
        <input data-bind="value: last" />
    </div>
    <button data-bind:"click: clickClose">Close</button>
</div>
```

and your ViewModel:

```
var profileModel = {
   first: ko.observable("First name"),
   last: ko.observable("Last name"),
   name: "profile"
 };

var settingsModel = {
  isActive: ko.observable(true),
  name: "settings"
};

var notificationsModel = {
  emailAddress: ko.observable("sample@mail.net") 
  name:"notifications" 
};

var shellModel = {
    sections: ko.observableArray([profileModel, settingsModel, notificationsModel]),
    selectedSection: ko.observable(), 
    clickClose: function() {
        this.selectedSection(null);
    },
    sectionChangedClick: function(section) {
        this.selectedSection(section);
    }  
}
ko.applyBindings(shellModel);
```

Just guessing, a easy fiddle would be nice.